# What's the best way to assign a method body at construction time when using Moose?

Tags: perl, moose

I'm using `Moose` (specifically `MooseX::Declare`) to create an iterator object, `Iter` which has a `next` method that advances state and returns `0` or `1` as required for use in a `while` statement. The problem I'm running into is that depending on the existence of one of the construction parameters, `next` needs to perform two very different sets of operations. The way I see it I have five options:

1. if ... then in `next` method
2. subclass
3. hash dispatch
4. symbol table manipulation
5. put methods in different modules and load required one at construction time

**Number 1** is just amateur.

**Number 2** is, I suppose, the proper OOP way of doing things.  I have no objections to doing it that way but seems a little bit overkill simply to override a single method.

I've often used **Number 3** in the past when working procedurally or pseudo-functionally and it's what I'm doing now.

**Number 4** is, as we all know, fraught with peril and I know nothing about Moose Guts to want to start messing around when unnecessary.

The last item, **number 5** seems to me to be the most sensible (and Perlish) but like Number 2, is a little too much work.  I'm really wondering if there's a fifth way I haven't considered such as hooking into the metaclass or perhaps a `MooseX` module that is reasonably mature.

Comment: You might want to further explain what the different actions are that the iterator should perform. It's hard to give design advice without knowing the full use-case.

Comment: Well, I'm really looking for a best practice not implementation specifics. What I have works just fine but is hash dispatching really want I want to do within the `Moose` paradigm?  That is, what is the 'Moosy' way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass your 'next' subref into the constructor and save it in an attribute:

```
has next => (
    isa => 'CodeRef',
    required => 1,
    traits => ['Code'],
    handles => { next => 'execute_method' },
);
```

With the 'execute_method' handler provided by the [native attribute 'Code' trait](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Meta/Attribute/Native/Trait/Code.pm), you can call the 'next' method as a normal method and it will find the subref body in the attribute.

If you want to pre-define the subref body/ies and decide at construction time which version to use, you could set the value of 'next' in a builder sub according to other conditions of the object:

```
has next => (
    # ...
    lazy => 1,
    default => sub {
         my $self = shift;
         return sub { ... } if $self->some_condition;
         # etc etc...
    },
);
```

Comment: Just to make it explicit for anyone reading this, the fact that there's no `is => '..'`, `reader`, or `accessor` is intentional.  Giving the delegated method the same name as the attribute is very elegant -- it exposes exactly the needed functionality with a minimum of potential confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to dynamically apply a role:

```
package Iter;
use Moose;
use Moose::Util qw(apply_all_roles);

has next_role => (is => 'ro');

sub BUILD {
    my $self = shift;
    apply_all_roles($self, $self->next_role);
}
```