# Object construction / method overloading

Tags: perl, moose

I'm looking for suggestions on neat, maintainable and testable ways to handle situations such as the following, where different combinations of parameters must be interpreted in different ways by the object's methods:

```
# Every 2 days.
$event = Event::Recurrence->new( recurs => 'daily', interval => 2 );

# 1st and 2nd day of every 3rd week.
$event = Event::Recurrence->new( recurs => 'weekly',  days => [1, 2], interval => 3 );

# 1st and 2nd day of every 4th month.
$event = Event::Recurrence->new( recurs => 'monthly', days => [1, 2], interval => 4 );

# 1st and 2nd day of the 2nd and 3rd week of every month.
$event = Event::Recurrence->new( recurs => 'monthly', days => [1, 2], weeks => [2, 3], interval => 1 );

# 1st and 2nd day of the 2nd and 3rd week of every year.
$event = Event::Recurrence->new( recurs => 'yearly',  days => [1, 2], weeks => [2, 3], interval => 1 );

# 1st and 2nd day of the 2nd and 3rd week of the 3rd and 4th months of every 5th year.
$event = Event::Recurrence->new( recurs => 'yearly',  days => [1, 2], weeks => [2, 3], months => [3, 4], interval => 5 );

# Do something with the event object.
$set = $event->get_set();
```

`get_set()` will function differently depending on the construction parameters.

I'm not looking for ways to implement the date handling - I'm using recurring events to illustrate the type of problem.  Instead,  I'm looking for more generic information on good ways to handle dispatching the different possible combinations of parameters to appropriate methods.  I'm using Moose, so Moose/OO patterns are welcome.

The above examples can be broadly split into different types of events: daily, weekly, monthly and yearly.  Each will handle the remaining parameters differently, but the end result will be the same type of object - a set of recurring events on which certains operations can be performed (getting the start and end dates, determining intersections, and so on).

`get_set()` could therefore implement a dispatch table to handle all the possible combinations of parameters, calling a separate method for each - but that feels messy.

I could create a [CodeRef](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Meta/Attribute/Native/Trait/Code.pm) attribute along with separate classes for the different recurrence types (`Event::Recurrence::Daily`, `Event::Recurrence::Weekly`, and so on), and assign the appropriate class to the attribute at construction time, similar to the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442520/whats-the-best-way-to-assign-a-method-body-at-construction-time-when-using-moose) - although I'm not sure how I would implement that.

Comment: Why should a method do different things for different sets of parameters? Have you tried coming up with a system that can do recurring events without have to care about their period? I'd look for a simpler solution before you get too wacky with this way of thinking.

Comment: @brian d foy: I was using [DateTime::Event::Recurrence](http://search.cpan.org/~fglock/DateTime-Event-Recurrence-0.16/lib/DateTime/Event/Recurrence.pm), but it doesn't handle some recurrences the way I'd like. Instead, I'm using [DateTime::Set->from_recurrence](http://search.cpan.org/~fglock/DateTime-Set-0.31/lib/DateTime/Set.pm) to create recurring events.  I want to follow a similar pattern to DateTime::Event::Recurrence, where `days`, `weeks` have different meanings depending on the presence or absence of other parameters. E.g., `days` can mean day of week, or day of month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should have separate subclasses for each kind of recurring event, e.g. a  DailyRecurringEvent class, WeeklyRecurringEvent class, MonthlyRecurringEvent class, etc.

(Note: daily and weekly recurring events could be implemented as instances of an "every n-day recurring event", i.e. n = 1 for daily events and n = 7 for weekly events.)

Instead of calling `->get_set` on your event objects, I would treat the objects themselves as "event sets". Now the question is: what operations do you want to support on your sets and what other supporting classes might you need.

An example: Suppose you want to support an operation that gets the next occurring event from an event set beyond a certain day. Call this operation "next_event_after". Implementubg this for each of the above classes (i.e. daily, weekly, monthly, yearly) is pretty straight forward.

Now you said you want to be able to take the intersection of event sets. How about a new class called "EventSetIntersection" which represents the intersection of a collection of event sets. The operation "next_event_after" for an intersection might be implemented something like this:

```
package EventSetIntersection;

use Moose;
has event_sets => (
  is => 'rw',
  isa => 'Array[EventSets]',
);
sub next_event_after {
  my ($self, $date) = @_;
  return min { $_->next_event_after($date) } @{ $self->event_sets };
}
```

Recall that your original classes were EventSets, so you can create the intersection directly:

```
my $weekely_event = WeeklyEvent->new(...);
my $yearly_event = YearlyEvent->new(...);
my $intersection = EventSetIntersection->new( event_sets => [ $weekly, $yearly ]);
```

Comment: This is similar to the method I chose to implement, but I eventually managed to parse the code down to such a degree that separate classes were unnecessary. Instead, I have a single `Event::Recurrence` class which has `daily`, `weekly`, `monthly` and `yearly` methods.  It turned out not to be as messy as I thought it would - in fact, it's rather neat :-)